# Collections sharing for Client/Server side

Tags: meteor

I found a code snippet in book "Getting Started with Meteor.js" :

```
var lists= new Meteor.Collection("Lists");  

if (Meteor.isClient) { 
    //lists here is unreachable
}
if (Meteor.isServer) { 
    //lists here is unreachable
}
```

After launching an example `lists` is `undefined` for client/server side. Does this method of sharing collections is still valid for Meteor v0.9.3? The book is "quite old" (First published: December 2012) if one takes account of the status of meteor.js.

Comment: It is still valid but not very used beyond toy projects. (client/server directories for separating code is much preferable). There is a typo in your example (Meteor.isSever lacks an S).

Comment: Thanks. I means that I have problem on my side. I updated the code.

Comment: If you want a trustworthy codebase try duplicating the official examples locally and play around with the code : `meteor create --example leaderboard` There are also examples named todos, parties and wordplay.

Comment: Thank you. After quick investigation (of leaderboard example) I found that removing `var` keyword for `lists` causes the browser debugger to see `lists`... But at the same time it makes `lists` to be a global variable, what it's not well seen.

Comment: The removal of `var` keyword is mainly used to "export" variables and be able to reference them in other source files. If you want to debug just set breakpoints to see variables values at a precise point in execution.

Comment: Thank you. `var` in the book and a following after the comment clearly suggests that `lists` is a global variable (The author even suggests to search it by browser debugger, same as it would be an `window` object). It is not global var. So, where `var lists` is put if I wanted to search it by Browser Debugger?

Comment: You'd setup breakpoints to access the current browser memory, please Google about it as it's out of the scope of Meteor programming anyway :) https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging